# How to build a responsive Vuetify app bar

Tags: javascript, vue.js, material-design, vuex, vuetify.js

I am attempting to set up a responsive Vuetify app bar in a Vue.js project. The navigation links are rendered in a 3-dot drop down menu when viewed on a mobile screen.

```
<v-app>
    <v-app-bar color="indigo" dark fixed app>
      <v-toolbar-title>Toolbar Mobile Menu</v-toolbar-title>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-toolbar-items class="hidden-sm-and-down">
        <v-btn text to="create">
          <span class="mr-2" v-if="activeUser">Create Post</span>
        </v-btn>
        <v-btn text to="/">
          <span class="mr-2" v-if="activeUser">All Posts</span>
        </v-btn>
      </v-toolbar-items>

      <v-menu class="hidden-md-and-up">
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
          <v-btn icon v-on="on">
            <v-icon>mdi-dots-vertical</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
        </template>

        <v-list>
          <v-list-item v-if="activeUser" to="create">
            <v-list-item-title>Create Post</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item>
          <v-list-item v-if="activeUser" to="/">
            <v-list-item-title>All Posts</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item>
        </v-list>
      </v-menu>
    </v-app-bar>
    <v-content>
      <router-view></router-view>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
```

The problem is that the 3-dot button renders in both full screen and mobile. I of course want that button to by visible only in mobile. To fix this, I attempted to nest the button inside the `v-toolbar-items` tags, but that also did not work. Any recommendations on how to configure this app bar to display the 3-dots button only in mobile view? Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

I usually make myself a little helper function

```js
computed: {
   isMobile() {
      return this.$vuetify.breakpoint.xsOnly;
   }
}
```

The different available breakpoints are listed [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/breakpoints#breakpoint-service-object).

Then you can use it in your template like

```html
<v-menu v-if="isMobile">
      
</v-menu>
```

Alternatively, you can just use the `$vuetify` directly in your markup.

```html
<v-menu v-if="$vuetify.breakpoint.xsOnly">
          
</v-menu>
```

Comment: The helper function can be done as a computed property

Answer (score 1):

Regarding Vue3 and vuetify3 you need to use`this.$vuetify.display.xs`

Comment: Can you add some explanations how this can solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

In addition to previous answers by @discolor and @Jaysanf:

If you use the Vue3 Composition API with Vuetify3, you can leverage the "useDisplay" hook

```html
<script setup>
    import { computed, unref } from 'vue'
    import { useDisplay } from 'vuetify'

    const display = useDisplay()

    const isMobile = computed(() => {
      return unref(display.mobile)
    })
</script>
```

Then you can use `isMobile` in the template to display or not something in a mobile view :

```html
<template>
    <v-menu v-if="isMobile">
          // This menu will be shown only in mobile-view
    </v-menu>
</template>
```

> The reason why using `unref(display.mobile)` is due to the fact that `display.mobile` is already a *Ref*. Not using `unref()` here will leads to unwanted behavior while using `isMobile` in the template and in the script
>
> So instead of having a `ComputedRef<Ref<boolean>>` (forcing you to use `isMobile.value` in the template, which is counter-intuitive), just use `unref()` to make a `ComputedRef<boolean>`